# If column match with value, use gsub and print value to another column

Tags: if-statement, awk, gsub

I use some example:

INPUT:

```
0.6     0.7    A:0.01   -       0
C:0.01  0.1    -        0.2     0
0.7     0.02   G:0.2    -       0
0.5     0.23   0.1      T:0.05  0
0.1     0.2    0.3      0.58    0
```

So, if some column has a value start with A C T or G I would like to change it to "0" or "-" and last column change to "W" (it is $34 $35 $36 $37 $38 )

OUTPUT:

```
0.6     0.7    0        -       W
0       0.1    -        0.2     W
0.7     0.02   0        -       W
0.5     0.23   0.1      0       W
0.1     0.2    0.3      0.58    0
```

I would like to use awk.

```
awk '{if($34=="^:^");gsub($34,"*","0") && gsub($38,"0","W"); else print}' file
```

and same for other columns.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about like this:

```
$ awk '{for(i=1;i<=4;i++){if ($i ~ /A:|C:|T:|G:/){$i=0; $NF="W"}}}1' file | column -t
0.6  0.7   0    -     W
0    0.1   -    0.2   W
0.7  0.02  0    -     W
0.5  0.23  0.1  0     W
0.1  0.2   0.3  0.58  0
```

In a more readable format:

```
$ awk '{  
          for(i=1;i<=4;i++) {           # Loop through the fieds
             if ($i ~ /A:|C:|T:|G:/) {  # If current field matches pattern
                 $i=0                   # Replace it with zero
                 $NF="W"                # And make the last field a 'W'
             }
          }
       }1' file | column -t
```

If you want to limit it to specific columns, you can use an array:

```
awk '{c="1,3";split(c,cols,/,/);for(i in cols){if ($cols[i] ~ /A:|C:|T:|G:/){$cols[i]=0; $NF="W"}}}1' file | column -t
```

Answer (score 1):

what about something like this:

`awk -v OFS="\t" '{if (gsub(/G:|C:|A:|T:/, "0")) print $1,$2,$3,$4,"W"; else print $0}`'

And then replace values strarting 00 to zero.

Comment: awk -v OFS="\t" '{if (gsub(/G|C:|A:|T:/, "@")) print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,"W"; else print $0}' erase.txt | awk 'BEGIN { FS = OFS = "\t" } { for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if($i ~ /@/) $i=0 }; 1'

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about spacing:

```
$ awk 'gsub(/[ACGT][^[:space:]]+/,0){$NF="W"}1' file
0.6 0.7 0 - W
0 0.1 - 0.2 W
0.7 0.02 0 - W
0.5 0.23 0.1 0 W
0.1     0.2    0.3      0.58    0
```

if you do:

```
$ awk 'gsub(/[ACGT][^[:space:]]+/,0){$NF="W"}1' file | column -t
0.6  0.7   0    -     W
0    0.1   -    0.2   W
0.7  0.02  0    -     W
0.5  0.23  0.1  0     W
0.1  0.2   0.3  0.58  0
```